# Runtime error 13

Tags: excel, vba

i am running into some troubles with some really easy code, I have read multiple posts and forums, but do not seem to be able to find the issue:

```
Sub ownership()
 Dim row, column, x, y As Integer
 For row = 2 To 42
  For column = 4 To 18
   For x = 2 To 16
    For y = 5 To 45
     If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("orka").Cells(3, row).Text = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("values").Cells(x, y).Text, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("orka").Cells(2, row).Value) Then ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("orka").Cells(column, row).Text = "X"
    Next
   Next
  Next
 Next
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot
s

Comment: Two suggestions.  **(1)**  In `.Cells(A, B)`, A is the row and B is the column.  You have them the other way round.  **(2)**  Almost certainly the problem is `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("orka").Cells(2, row).Value` not being an integer.  When the macro stops for error 13, examine the value of this cell.

Comment: thanks a lot, I assumed I did something very basic wrong...

Answer (score 0):

That is  because `.Text` is a read only property. Use `.Value` instead. You cannot say

`Range("A1").Text = "Blah Blah"`

You can however do this

`MsgBox Range("A1").Text`

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub ownership()
    Dim row  As Integer, column  As Integer, x  As Integer, y As Integer

    For row = 2 To 42
        For column = 4 To 18
            For x = 2 To 16
                For y = 5 To 45
                    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("orka").Cells(3, row).Value = _
                    Left(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("values").Cells(x, y).Text, _
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("orka").Cells(2, row).Value) Then _
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("orka").Cells(column, row).Value = "X"
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Also in VBA when you declare variables as

```
Dim row, column, x, y As Integer
```

Then only the last variable `y` in this case will be declared as Integer and the rest will be declared as `Variant`. The correct way is to declare it like I have doen it above.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it still returns a runtime error 13, even when I replace the .text within the left function.

Comment: I just tried the code above. It works fine now. Did you try the code as it is from above?

Comment: yes, just removed the _ and put the if statement in one row.
Do i need to activate a certain refernce for the code to work?
what does the "Option Explicit" stand for?

Comment: `Option Explicit` is to ensure that you have declared all your variables. You can delete that for a moment (for testing purpose) if you have other code in the same module and you have not declared the variables. Otherwise Don't delete anything. Just copy the above code to new module as it is and then run it.

Comment: can you upload your file at wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: Also check if there is any error in your data in your `values sheet` because of Formulas.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I cannot do that due to confidentiality issues. I will do it the monkey way (comparing ~600 names for same beginning)

Comment: You can debug the code, I have a feeling that one of the cells has a "Formula Error"